# Portal linking order and multiple fields

Tags: ingress

I'd like to check my understanding of field creation is correct. Here is a map:

[image: Map]

1. If I link A to D now, it will only create the field ABD and not also the field ACD?  (Or does it create ACD but not ABD?)
2. However, suppose the link BD did not exist yet; then I could link AD to create the field ACD; and then I could link D to B creating 2 more fields DBC and ABD.

So (any larger strategy notwithstanding) doing it the second way would end up with 1 more field, and thus more AP and MU.

Is this all correct?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=priezq6Dm4Y

Comment: Ingress? Is that the cyberpunk spinoff of Pokemon Go?

Comment: @Studoku you got it

Comment: @Studoku since 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking A and D will create field ACD,  and not create ABD.  If a link would create two or more overlapping fields, only the *largest* of those fields is created.

If A and D are linked, and then C is destroyed, it would leave ABD all connected but with no field (this is called a *null field*).